# Incrementing dates after a certain number of entries (in this case 9)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I would like for a date to increment after 9 entries like the below:

```
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/1/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/2/2018
1/3/2018
1/3/2018
1/3/2018
1/3/2018
1/3/2018
1/3/2018
1/3/2018
1/3/2018
1/3/2018
```

etc. until the end of the year. Is there anyway to automatically have this happen. I have tried highlighting and dragging but it never increments, just repeats from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to put 9 1/1/2018 in A1:A9 then in A10 put

```
=A1+1
```

then copy down.

[image]

---

Now if you want one formula in that you can drag down from A2.

Put the starting date in A1 and this formula in A2:

```
=$A$1+INT((ROW(1:1))/9)
```

Then copy down.

[image]

Comment: @B.steiner if this worked for you then please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.